# 2003 chevy silverado 2500 hd no power

Tags: electrical, starting, chevrolet, gasoline

**no power to head lights cab lights ignition or steering column the battery has 12-4 
  volts coming out of it. tried jumping with another car and nothing happened**.

Comment: Did the truck crank and start yesterday? If it cranked and ran yesterday, has any work been done on the truck since then? If it didn't run yesterday, how long has it been parked, and what worked and didn't work when it last ran?

Answer (score 1):

I would first check that both sides of the battery cables are free of corrosion and connected correctly. Take a good look at the ground cable.
Also when you say the battery is putting out 12.4v you should check if that is the same when you put your test-leads one on the positive battery post and the other on a frame screw or the engine. That should give you a better idea if there is an issue with battery ground.
The next thing to check would be the fuses. Especially if there is a master fuse on the battery cable.